# Python 3.X: How to insert new row in excel using Xlrd3 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

So I am using Xlrd3 to read and write to an excel sheet. The problem I am running into is I want to find an easy way to insert a blank row in between two non-blank rows. Is there a function or an easy way to do this? I have looked through the documentation and could not find anything, but was hoping i just missed it.

If there is no simple way to do this then maybe someone can direct me to a way to do this? It is a very long file (close to 500 lines) and maybe 10 or so columns per row and I need to just at certain times push everything at a certain point down and insert a new row blank row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd` is for reading only.  `xlwt` will write.  [`xlutils`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) will help with re-writing a new file from what you have read.